# dotnet Segmentation Fault on Ubuntu: i have only 174 MB free RAM

Tags: ubuntu, ram, segmentation-fault

When i run `dotnet` or `dotnet --list-sdks` or `dotnet --list-runtimes` it works, but if i run a project or even `dotnet --help` or `dotnet --info` , i get

```
Segmentation fault
```

In `/var/log/syslog` i see:

```
[ 3110.470681] dotnet[30805]: segfault at 3610000036f ip 00007fbd622f444c sp 00007fbd5c769c10 error 4 in libcoreclr.so[7fbd621ec000+2$
```

This is my free memory:

```
~# free -h

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        6.3G        174M         59M        9.2G        9.0G
Swap:          2.0G         57M        1.9G
```

Is the RAM shortage to blame? Should i double it?
dotnet used to work before i installed memory-heavy daemons ( crypto wallets ).

EDIT: the RAM is not the problem apparently. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have 9G of available RAM, so no, memory shortage isn’t to blame here.

Comment: Upvoted thank you